# How to get the real filelocations of all real svg-files on commons.wikimedia?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, export, wikimedia-commons

On 7.April I asked here and on the wikipedia help-desk how to get such a list: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk/Archives/2015_April_7#How_to_get_a_list_of_all_.svg_files_on_Wikipedia.org_and_commons.wikimedia.org.3F)

I now downloaded the file "commonswiki-20150417-all-titles".

Then I get all entries that end with ".svg".

So far, so good.

First problem: But how can I automatically find out the path to the real svg-file and not just a preview site with a png or jpg file? The all-titles file only gives the file name, and not the path.

Example: Preview site: commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Blason_ville_fr_Servigny-l%C3%A8s-Sainte-Barbe_57.svg
Real svg-file: upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Blason_ville_fr_Servigny-l%C3%A8s-Ste-Barbe_57.svg

Second problem: Some files seem to need to be added a "File:" prefix to to find the preview site. For example: 11-cube_t0_B5.svg
commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:11-cube_t0_B5.svg

 But that "File:" is not needed for the real svg-file path.

How is this dump-file used?

In short: How to get the real path to the real svg-files?

Answer (score 3):

From File:A to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/**Special:Redirect/file/A**

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Redirect/file/11-cube_t0_B5.svg redirects to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/11-cube_t0_B5.svg